# JavaScript timing, jQuery fadeIn fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function that I wrote that transitions three div elements using a fade in/out effect. The event is triggered when a user clicks a link. Here's my code:

```
$(".link1").click(function () {
   $(".feature1").fadeIn(1000);
   $(".feature2").fadeOut(1000);
   $(".feature3").fadeOut(1000);
});

$(".link2").click(function () {
   $(".feature1").fadeOut(1000);
   $(".feature2").fadeIn(1000);
   $(".feature3").fadeOut(1000);
});

$(".link3").click(function () {
   $(".feature1").fadeOut(1000);
   $(".feature2").fadeOut(1000);
   $(".feature3").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

I need to be able to set some sort of timer so that these transitions happen automatically every 8 seconds or so. I also want them to "loop" essentially, so that if we get to the third div in the set, it returns to the first div.

Comment: show your HTML and CSS too. meanwhile read [`jQuery Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Comment: i made basic [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/5VKnF/) for you.

Comment: Can't you optimize your code like this: $(".feature1, .feature2, .feature3").fadeOut(1000);

or am I imagining things? http://jsfiddle.net/ZKt7w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this kind of what you mean?

```
setInterval(myFunction,8000);
```

The setInterval function in javascript runs a function every (in this case) 8 seconds set in it's second parameter. You'll notice there are no parenthesis when you call your function.

You can also call an anonymous function like this:

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
```

If you want to be able to control this via a click event you can do something like this:

```
var loop;
$(elem).click(function(){
    loop = setInterval(fades,8000);
});

function fades(){
    $(".feature1").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".feature2").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".feature3").fadeOut(1000);
}
```

And you can stop the loop this way: `clearInterval(loop);`

Comment: This looks great! `setInterval` is what I was looking for. If I had more reputation I'd upvote this. I'll accept one SO allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/F4X46/1/

```
var i = 1,
    t;

function makeTO() {
    t = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('test');
        if (i++ === 3) {
            i = 1;
        }
        $(".link" + i).trigger('click');
    }, 8000);
}
$(".link1").click(function() {
    i = 1;
    clearTimeout(t);
    makeTO();
    $(".feature1").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".feature2").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".feature3").fadeOut(1000);
});

$(".link2").click(function() {
    i = 2;
    clearTimeout(t);
    makeTO();
    $(".feature1").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".feature2").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".feature3").fadeOut(1000);
});

$(".link3").click(function() {
    i = 3;
    clearTimeout(t);
    makeTO();
    $(".feature1").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".feature2").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".feature3").fadeIn(1000);
});
makeTO();
```

Comment: @George.P as long as I can be of help it's okay :]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something. please see **[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xe5Ju/)**

#### HTML

```
<a class="link1" href="javascript:void(0)"> Link1 </a>
<a class="link2" href="javascript:void(0)" > Link2 </a>
<a class="link3" href="javascript:void(0)" > Link3 </a>
<div class="feature1">Feature1 div</div>
<div class="feature2">Feature2 div</div>
<div class="feature3">Feature3 div</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
a { font:bold 13px verdana; padding:4px}
div { border:1px solid grey; padding:3px;width:150px;height:90px;margin:3px;}
.feature1 { background-color: #f00; }
.feature2 { background-color: #0f0; }
.feature3 { background-color: #00f; }​
```

#### jQuery

```
(function () {
    var i =0;
    var doFade= function() {        
        i = (i%3)+1;
        //console.log(i);
        $("div[class^=feature]").fadeOut(1000);
        $('.feature'+i+'').fadeIn(1000);                
    };
    doFade();
    window.setInterval(doFade, 2000);
})();​
```

Answer (score 0):

For timing issues in jQuery use the plugin [jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/).

Select all your .feature* in jQuery and then:

```
$(".feature1,.feature2,.feature3").repeat()
    .each($).fadeIn(1000).siblings().fadeOut(1000).wait(3000).all()
```

Nice. Isn't it?

See this running on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/creativecouple/7avaJ/).